# What is the difference between Cramer and Vaidman?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Two very interesting new papers on arXiv last night by Lev Vaidman and friends lead me to ask about the differences between Cramer's transactional interpretation of quantum mechanics (TIQM) and the two state vector formalism (TSVF) advanced by Aharonov, Vaidman and others.  At a first look, they both seem very similar to me.
The two papers:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7474  “The past of a quantum particle”,  and
http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7469  “Asking a particle where it has been”.
From these two papers, you can find further references for TSVF, including its origin.
For TIQM, you can start with Wikipedia, and also trace back to the origin.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_interpretation

Comment: TSVF is on Wikipedia [too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_vector_formalism).